# Issue with netbeans "Project Folder already exists and is not empty"

Tags: java, netbeans

Creating new project under Java with ant > java application will have the error message "Project Folder already exists and is not empty".
Things I have attempted

1. Reinstall netbeans, jdk
2. Deleting off files from netbeansproject folders
   None of these seems to work

Please advise thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check in your C:\Users......\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjects folder for 'ant' folder and delete it or delete the project from the workspace of NetBeans.
Also try to make a new project under some other name and check if that works.
If these don't work, maybe you JDK didn't get installed or updated properly.